# NSTimer won't invalidate on iPad but works fine on iPhone

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nstimer

I have a repeating timer that runs down a clock. During the clock running down I call stopTimer and the clock should stop. This has worked 100% on the iPhone however on the iPad it will sometimes fail to stop the timer. This happens about 50% of the time.
The NSLog's are called in the stop method.

Here's my timer code:

```
- (void)startSliderTimer
{
    // Get start time
    [self stopTimer];
    startTime = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] + kmaxTimePerSlider;
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01f target:self selector:@selector(updateClock) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)updateClock
{
    NSTimeInterval currentTimer = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
    NSTimeInterval currentTimeLeft = startTime - currentTimer;
    if (currentTimeLeft >= 0) {
        int seconds = currentTimeLeft;
        float milliseconds = currentTimeLeft - seconds;
        int mill = milliseconds * 1000;
        NSString* displayTime = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%02d:%03d",seconds,mill];
        timerLbl.text = displayTime;
    } else {
        [self tooSlow];
    }
}

- (void) stopTimer
{
    NSLog(@"%s",__FUNCTION__);
    if (self.timer) {
        NSLog(@"Stop Timer");
        [self.timer invalidate];
        self.timer = nil;
    }
}
```

I have just tried running the timer like this as suggestion in another question/answer but it still doesn't always invalidate:

```
self.timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.01f target:self selector:@selector(updateClock) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:self.timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

Comment: Does your app have any scrolling happening during the timer? That triggers a different kind of runloop, which would cause the timer not to fire or to fire late.

Comment: Yes it does, the whole game is based on scrolling!
The timer fires just fine, because the clock is updated every 0.01 second. I checked the .isValid property and it is valid so must be a run loop problem. Why would this only be different on iPad? And what can I do to get around it (Run the timer on another run loop?)

Comment: Sorry, it's not scrolling, i'm using UISliders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the timer without scheduling it using a `+timerWith...` method, then schedule it on the runloop yourself using `[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes]` to run it on all runloops. Let me know if that works.

Comment: I tried that just before you wrote it here. I tried with both mainRunLoop and currentRunLoop, but it doesn't help. The timer runs fine, it just won't stop sometimes.

Comment: Hmm. Make sure your timer callback looks like - (void)timerFireMethod:(NSTimer*)theTimer.

Comment: I feel so stupid now. There isn't anything wrong with the timer! Because I was only counting down 1 second it was hard to notice, but I wasn't resetting an int to 0 before starting a new game! Doh! Sorry, but thanks all the same.

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out :)

Comment: Thanks, I guess this is what happens when you code all day without a break!

Answer (score 0):

For a game, perhaps you should use CADisplayLink instead of NSTimer.